# Finding the law of probabily of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let 
$X : \Omega \to P(\{1,.....,n\})=X(\Omega)$ such that $X \sim U( P(\{1,.....,n\})$ , and 
$X_{1},...,X_{N}$  random variables
Identically independently distributed and having the same law as $X$ . 
Compute the Law of $Y=|\cap_{i\in [[1,N]]} X_{i}|$ . 
Sorry it's my first time on this forum,I apologise for my bad english. 
I don't figure out what $Y(\Omega)$ is $Y$ is a random variable representing the cardinal of the intersection above , $P(\{1,.....,n\})$ is the set  of all subsets of $[[1,n]]$ what I understanded , is that if $S_{k}$ is a subset of $[[1,n]]$ with $k$ element then $p(X=S_{k})=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ but I have some trouble to understand the evenement $Y=k$ , any help please , Thank's .

Comment: what is $P(\{1,\ldots n\})?$ Power set? Explain your notation (and yes, indicate your thoughts on the problem)

Comment: `Binomial(N,1/2^N)`. Now please explain what you did.

Comment: I edited my post sorry it's my first time on the forum , and my english is not that good , thank's for your help

Comment: @Did can you please check my proof I found Binomial(2^{N} ,1/2^N) ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just finished the lecons of probability we have two days ago , and I still have trouble , to imagine $\Omega$ and $Z(\Omega)$ intuitively , 
probability is still so new for me , if someone can give me any recommendation of how I need to represent it in my head , to better understand how the random variables work , it would be so help full . here is my tought on the problem , $P(\{1,....,n\})$ represent the Set of all subsets of 
$[[1,n]]$ since $X$ is the uniforme law on this set , then what I understanded is that it mean that , if $S_{k}$ is a subset of $[[1,n]]$ 
 then $p(X=S_{k})=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$  , then I had trouble to visualise how $Y$ work but today by thinking more about it , here what I figured out (hope it make sens , and i am not thinking a delirium) , 
since $Y$ is the random variable of the cardinal of the intesection above the evenement $Y=m$ mean that $m$ evenement
$X_{i_{1}}(S_{i_{1}})......X_{i_{m}}(S_{i_{m}})$  happened  , hence 
$(Y=m)=\{ \cup_{(S_{i_{j}})_{j\in [[1,m]] }} (X_{i_{1}}=S_{i_{1}} , ..., X_{i_{m}}=S_{i_{m}}\}$  since this reunion is disjoint , and the variables are identically independtly distributed then 
$p(Y=m)=\sum_{(S_{i_{j}})_{j\in [[1,m]] }} \frac{1}{2^{nm}}$ since $(S_{i_{j}})_{j\in [[1,m]] }$ is a $m$ list choosen from $S_{1} , ...., S_{2^{n}}$
hence $p(Y=m)=\frac{\binom{2^{n}}{m}}{2^{nm}}$ . if I don't make any nonesense thanks